# Avoid username/password prompt when running git credential fill

Tags: node.js, git, shell

I'm trying to run the `git credential fill` command from a Node.js program. I want to use it to check whether there is a stored username/password for a given URL. If there is one, I'm parsing the output (*stdout*) of the `git credential` command to get the stored username and password.

If the OS credential helper does not have a stored username/password for the URL, I want the program to terminate silently. Unfortunately, this does not work. When running my program from a shell, the `git credential fill` command asks for username and password in the terminal:

```
$ git credential fill
url=http://foo.foo

Username for 'http://foo.foo': ^C
```

In the above example, I stopped the execution by pressing *Ctrl+C* since I'm not interested in entering a username/password.

Is there a way to run `git credential fill` so that it does not ask for a username/password if it does not have one, and simply terminates silently?

When I call the `git credential fill` from a Node.js program using the `child_process.spawn` function, the same happens:

```
var output;

var command = spawn('git', ['credential', 'fill']);

command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    output = data;
});

command.stdout.on('end', function () {
    // callback is a function defined outside that receives the git command's output.
    callback(output);
});

command.stdin.write('url=http://foo\n\n');
```

When running this from a standard bash shell, the same happens, it asks for username/password again.

When I run the above program from inside the WebStorm IDE using its run mode, the git credential program is not asking for username/password, it simply terminates silently. It looks like WebStorm runs this program in a shell that does not support user input. Is there a way to achieve the same when running in a shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work using the `detached: true` attribute of the `spawn` function:

```
var command = spawn('git', ['credential', 'fill'], { detached: true });
```

According to the [Node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), the `detached` option makes the spawned process the leader of a new process group. This seems to trick Git into thinking that it shouldn't ask for the username/password on the TTY.

**Update**: The above only seems to work for running the code on Mac OS X. On Windows, the `detached` option causes the spawned program to run in a second command window, and it looks like the stdin/stdout connection between the calling and the spawned program does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable to `true` or `false`.

With either, you'll get the output if `git credential fill` does not need to
ask for a password.

If `git` does not know the password with `GIT_ASKPASS=true`, the output will
have an empty password:

```sh
$ cat <<EOF | env GIT_ASKPASS=true git credential fill
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=allen

EOF
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=allen
password=
```

With `GIT_ASKPASS=false`:

```sh
$ cat <<EOF | env GIT_ASKPASS=false git credential fill
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=allen

EOF
error: unable to read askpass response from 'false'
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://allen@github.com': Device not configured
```